# commands to gather system information under unix

Tags: linux, ssh, unix

I have `ssh` access to a unix-based computer.  What are the best set of shell commands to help identify what kind of machine it is (e.g. CPU type, number of cores, cache sizes, memory size, manufacturer, model number), what OS it is running, what are its local disk drives, what software is installed (perhaps not in my default `PATH`), etc?

(Hopefully within a text-based shell session and without requiring root privilege.)

I already know of `df` to get information on mapped disks.

Comment: can you run `cat /proc/cpuinfo` also `lspci` and `lsusb` `uname -a` `cat /proc/version`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several commands for these pieces of information.

- `lspci`: Will show any PCI related information. Not needed to be run as root.
- `lscpu`: Will show any CPU related information. Not needed to be run as root.
- `lsscsi`: Will show any scsi/sata related information. Not needed to be run as root.
- `lsusb`: Will show any USB related information. Not needed to be run as root.
- `lsblk`: Will show any block devices related information. Not needed to be run as root.
- `dmidecode`: Will show DMI information shown in human-readable output. This command requires `root` privileges, though.
- `lshw`: Will show general information about hardware: CPU, memory, hard disks, PCI, network interfaces... probably the most complete command you will find. Might be run as non-root, however, it *might* truncate some information (and a warning will be shown).
- `free`: Information about memory: Total, used, cache...
- `cat /proc/meminfo` will also provide information about memory. Might be run as non-root.
- `cat /proc/cpuinfo` will also provide information about CPU of the machine. Might be run as non-root.

As far as software and OS goes, I doubt there is a "standard" command for all distributions. For example, on RHEL-based systems (like CentOS) distribution might be got running `cat /etc/redhat_release`. On Debian-based systems (like Ubuntu), you can run `lsb_release -a`.

For software info you can run `rpm -q` on `RHEL` based systems (like CentOS), and `dpkg -l` on Debian-based systems (like Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks; these pointers are very helpful.  I especially like `lscpu` and `free -g`.  Are there specific arguments for `rpm` to show all installed packages?  (unfortunately, I did not find `lshw`.)

Comment: Yes, you can run `rpm -qa` to list all packages.

Comment: Try installing the `lshw` package, it should provide the command as well.

Answer (score 1):

To display the hardware information and OS type in a text-based shell session use the command:

```
lshw -xml | less
```

The `-xml` option adds xml description tags to the list of hardware. Piping the output of `lshw` to the `less` program allows scrolling the output of `lshw`.

You will receive a warning if you are not a super-user.

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
```

and `lshw` will run anyway, however it will display less than the full amount of hardware information if you are not a super-user.

Comment: Unfortunately, `lshw` does not seem to exist -- at least in the default `PATH`.  (`lsb_release -a` shows `Fedora release 22`)

Comment: I tried `dnf install lshw` but it requires root access which I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the commands already provided,

- `dmesg`: will display the kernel ring buffer. Not needed to be run as root.
- `hwinfo`: an alternative to `lshw` that provides additional informations. BUT: requires root privileges to be run.

Concerning `lshw` and `hwinfo`: Personally, for the most complete breakdown of hardware information, I prefer to have both available. In my experience, `hwinfo` provides more detailed identification and adressing information , whereas `lshw` shows more details on hardware capabilities. However, `lshw` has the clear advantage of giving (albeit partly abridged) information when invoked from a non-root account.

Answer (score 0):

*Since neither any of the `ls...` commands nor `hwinfo` were usable for me (under Solaris), I ended up writing this as an alternative:*

Have a look at the info that `uname -X` provides: [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname#Examples)

from man page:

```
NAME
     uname - print name of current system

SYNOPSIS
     uname [-aimnprsvX]

     uname [-S system_name]

DESCRIPTION
     The uname utility prints information about the current  sys-
     tem on the standard output. When options are specified, sym-
     bols representing one or more system characteristics will be
     written to the standard output. If no options are specified,
     uname  prints  the  current  operating  system's  name.  The
     options  print  selected  information  returned by uname(2),
     sysinfo(2), or both.

OPTIONS
     The following options are supported:

     -a              Prints basic information currently available
                     from the system.

     -i              Prints the name of the platform.

     -m              Prints the machine  hardware  name  (class).
                     Use of this option is discouraged. Use uname
                     -p instead. See NOTES section below.

     -n              Prints the nodename  (the  nodename  is  the
                     name  by which the system is known to a com-
                     munications network).

     -p              Prints the current host's ISA  or  processor
                     type.

     -r              Prints the operating system release level.

     -s              Prints the name  of  the  operating  system.
                     This is the default.
...
     -v              Prints the operating system version.

     -X              Prints  expanded  system  information,   one
                     information element per line, as expected by
                     SCO   UNIX.   The   displayed    information
                     includes:
                       o  system name,  node,  release,  version,
                          machine, and number of CPUs.
                       o  BusType,  Serial,  and  Users  (set  to
                          "unknown" in Solaris)
                       o  OEM# and  Origin#  (set  to  0  and  1,
                          respectively)
```